# jQuery DataTables cant search long name

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im develop the jQuery DataTables , its works fine, but i had some issue ,  i can search for `1/30` but cant search this type word,

```
1/30 Reguler 100%Polyester CF Compacted
```

problem is   `<th style="width:50px;">Item Name</th>` column
 how can i fix it,

[image]

### [image]

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectid', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#hfRowItem1').val(parseInt($(this).parents('tr').children('td').eq(0).html()));
    $('#hfRowItem2').val(parseInt($(this).parents('tr').children('td').eq(4).html()));
    $('#btnFakeRowClick').trigger('click');
});

$(function Pageload() {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataTableInstance = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                "iDisplayLength": 5,
                "bStateSave": false,    //restore table state on page reload,
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sLengthMenu": 'Show <select><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option></select> entries'
                },
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                columns: [
                    {
                        'data': 'ProcessPlanId',
                        className: 'hide_column'
                    },
                    { 'data': 'ProcessPlanNo' },
                    { 'data': 'StyleName' },
                    { 'data': 'ItemName' },
                    { 'data': 'ColourNumber' },
                    {
                        'data': 'ProcessPlanDate',
                        'render': function (jsonDate) {
                            var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                            var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                            //return date.getDate() + '/' + month + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                            return ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + ("0" + month).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                        }
                    },
                    { 'data': 'ConfirmStatus' },
                    {
                        'data': null,
                        className: "center",
                        defaultContent: '<a href="" class="selectid">Select</a>', 'width': '5%'
                    }
                ],
                bServerSide: true,
                sAjaxSource: 'GenericHandlers/ProcessPlanDataHandler.ashx'
            });


            $('#datatable tfoot th').each(function () {
                if ($(this).index() != 0 && $(this).index() != 7) {
                    //var title = $('#datatable thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" class="dtSrchCol" placeholder="Search">');
                    if ($(this).index() == 5) {
                        $(this).find('input').addClass('datetimepicker');
                    }
                }
            });


            dataTableInstance.columns().every(function () {
                var datatableColumn = this;

                $(this.footer()).find('input').on('keyup change', function () {
                    datatableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
$(document).ready(Pageload);
```

---

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mpSrch" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width: 95%">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header btn-primary btn-sm" style="height: 40px;">
                                <button style="margin-top: -10px;" type="button" class="close btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                <h6 style="margin-top: -5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>Process Plan</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <div class="modal-content" style="margin-left: 15px;width: 1250px;padding: 2px;">
                                            <table id="datatable" class="datatableDisplay" font-size:"11pt">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Id</th>
                                                         <th style="width:50px;">Process Plan No</th>
                                                       <th style="width:50px;">Style Name</th>
                                                       <th style="width:50px;">Item Name</th>
                                                    <th style="width:50px;">Colour Number</th>
                                                      <th style="width:50px;">Process Plan Date</th>
                                                     <th style="width:50px;">Confirm Status</th>
                                                      <th style="margin-left:-25px;">Action</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                    <div id="eee">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                            <th></th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </div>
                                                </tfoot>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable smart filtering on DataTables which is on by default.  My understanding is that smart filtering will break up a string in to word parts by splitting search string on spaces and then using a regex to filter on the values in that column.  So I wouldn't be surprised if it choked on complex strings with spaces.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.smart